# How to write php code inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

My problem How to write php code inside javascript? How Can I do this ?
Thanks for your answers.

I want to write PHP code;

```
<?php if($this->session->userdata('kullaniciadi') == "") {echo "tiklama";} ?>
```

My JavaScript Codes;

```
new DC.Button({styles:"right_button tiklama <--- HERE",text:"Right",onClick:function(){self.onRightButtonClick();
```

Comment: Where do you want to add in js code?

Comment: you have html in your project? if you have, try to bind ( session->userdata('kullaniciadi') ) to html input, and you can access from javascript

Comment: if the user is not logged in and add tiklama class, if the user is logged in tiklama class delete

Comment: @GündoğduYakıcı, Are you pages PHP page or simple HTML pages? OR JS files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP** is a server-side language that executes on the server before the page even loads and **JavaScript** is a client-side language that executes on the browser. Hence, there's no way to write **PHP** in **JavaScript**, because the don't serve the same purpose.

If you want to contact a PHP page via JavaScript you'd better use an [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) request.

**Example use of an AJAX request:**

```
var
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest,
    response;

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (yhttp.readyState === 4 && yhttp.status === 200) {
        response = xhttp.responseText // This variable contains the response from PHP
    }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "YourPhpFile.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("number=" + number);
```

**In YourPhpFile.php:**

In this file, do the calculations you want to do and **`echo`** something that will identify if the operation succeeded or failed. Whatever you put after **`echo`** will be passed on to JavaScript:

```
echo "Success!"; // This string will be passed on to JavaScript
```

Then in JavaScript, after **`response = xhttp.responseText`** make a check and execute the appropriate code for your case.

Comment: Thats not entirely true. It is completely possible for PHP to calculate values and output **server-side** into HTML / Javascript

Comment: Providing the Page is **.php**

Comment: You just beat me @scottevans93. I was about to say that as you posted your comment :p To me, it seems like he's asking how to put **PHP** code in **JS** file.

Comment: Thanks for example how I can do ?

Answer (score 1):

```
new DC.Button({styles:"right_button <?php if($this->session->userdata('kullaniciadi') == "") {echo "tiklama";} ?>",text:"Right",onClick:function(){self.onRightButtonClick();
```

Within a PHP page, this should work how you described

Also, here is a shorthand version.

```
new DC.Button({styles:"right_button <?=($this->session->userdata('kullaniciadi')=="")? "tiklama": "";} ?>",text:"Right",onClick:function(){self.onRightButtonClick();
```

These solutions will require the file which contains the code to be executed by a web server before being served to the client.

Comment: Are your pages HTML **or** Javascript **or** PHP?

Comment: My page Codeigniter PHP

Comment: If you're pages are PHP pages, then providing your PHP code is syntactically correct it would work.